# Likelihood Lévy process

Tags: stochastic-processes, likelihood, point-process, measure-theory

Consider af complete observation sample path of a Levy process $X_t$ (wtr a poisson randommeasure $\mu$) on [0,t] concentrated on the integers. The parametrization is a family of Levy measures $\nu_{\theta}$, $\theta$ finite-dimensional. I need to show that the log-likelihood is given by: $l(\theta)=\sum_{0<s\leq t, \Delta X_s \neq 0} \log h_{\theta}(\Delta X_s) - t \nu_{\theta}(\mathbb{R})$,

where $h_{\theta}(m)=\nu_{\theta}(\{m\})$. I'm really on thin ice here.